# What is the proper way to deal with different encoding with DataFrames when source is not UTF-8. What is the workflow to avoid losing info?

Tags: dataframe, encoding, julia, odbc, dataframes.jl

```
let's say you create a connection 
conn=ODBC.Connection("connection string") 
df=DBInterface.execute(conn, "Select * from table;" )  |> DataFrame

you'll have your df, but you ll see you 've lost some info 

Name
Nicol\xc1 (Nicolás) ## the source is LATIN1 so you lose info.
```

so, we want to preserve the info

name

Nicolás

Also, writing in other encoding would be great to work around.